# Javascript keep variables value on all devices

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a notification panel but i have a problem with the "delete option". Here's the code:

```
<div id="notification">
  <span> Hi, i'm a title </span>
</div>
<button id="del" type="button" onClick="delete()">Delete Notification</button>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```js
function delete() {
    var notificationDisplay = "0"
    if (notificationDisplay == "0") {
      document.getElementById("notification").style.display = "none"
    } else {
      document.getElementById("notification").style.display = "block"
    }
```

I'd like to do that when you click the button the notification disappear on all browsers or devices (so i don't want to use cookies or HTML5 local storage). The problem is that when i refresh the page the notification return visible. How can i do to keep it "deleted"?

Comment: If this is in your default markup. How you suppose to delete this permanently using JavaScript?

Comment: i only want to keep it "display: none"

Comment: If you want to keep it as marked "read" for say, a user account, across all devices, you'd likely need a database.

Comment: Then save the state in the cookies or by default set it to display none and then toggle the display as per your requirement.

Comment: Under these conditions, a backend (maybe node.js and mongodb?) should be the easiest (and best) solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the state  on every refresh, you should save the state in local storage (or) cookies as these are persistent across page refreshes. If you want it to work across browsers, maintain the state in the backend and share it over a cookie.

Comment: A cookie or localStorage is only good for one device, not all, and the OP explicitly said *i don't want to use cookies or HTML5 local storage*.

Comment: Well then, you need to share it over a cookie and maintain the status of the notification (read/unread) in the backend.